# Solve this sytem of ode and describe its behavior.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

So after having made the transformation to polar coordinates, we have a system of ODE:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
r' & = r\left(\,{1 - r}\,\right)
\\[1mm]
\theta' & = r-1
\end{aligned}
\right.
\qquad\qquad\qquad\substack{\mbox{Note that both}\ {\displaystyle r\ \mbox{and}\ \theta}
\\[1mm]
\mbox{are functions of time.}}
$$

- My ODE is a bit rusty, but I think we can separate each ODE and solve them individually and get
  $\ln\left(\,{\left\vert\,{ r}\,\right\vert}\,\right) - \ln\left(\,{\left\vert\,{r - 1}\,\right\vert}\,\right) = t$ for the first ODE and $\theta =
  -\ln\left(\,{\left\vert\,{r}\,\right\vert}\,\right)$ for the second.
- Now I am not exactly sure how to describe the behavior of our system with these as our solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, from the given system,

$$\begin{cases}
r^{\prime}(t)&=&r(t)(1-r(t))& \ \ (1a) \\
\theta^{\prime}(t)&=&r(t)-1& \ \ (1b)
\end{cases},$$

written under the form:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{r^{\prime}(t)}{r(t)}&=&1-r(t)\\
\theta^{\prime}(t)&=&r(t)-1
\end{cases},$$

one can deduce :

$$-\frac{r^{\prime}(t)}{r(t)}=\theta^{\prime}(t)$$

$$-\frac{\tfrac{dr}{dt}}{r}=\tfrac{d \theta}{dt}$$

In this way, one can get rid of variable $t$ :

$$\frac{dr}{d \theta}=-r,$$

a classical differential equation whose solution is

$$r=Ke^{-\theta} \tag{2}$$

where $K$ is a constant given by the **initial conditions** $(r_0, \theta_0)$. As $r_0=Ke^{-\theta_0}$ implies $K=r0 e^{\theta_0}$), relationship (2) can be written under the form:

$$r=r_0 e^{\theta_0-\theta} \tag{3}$$

(3) is the polar equation of a **logarithmic spiral**.

This is the **trajectory**, the track left on the ground.

Now, how is the **behavior** of a point with the cinematics given by (1) ?

As this kind of spiral crosses the unit circle C (characterized by $r=1$), you see on (1a) or (1b) that the signs of $r'(t)$ and $\theta'(t)$ change.

Two cases, according to the initial conditions $(r_0,\theta_0)$ :

- If $r_0>1$, equations $(1a)$ and $(1b)$ give $r'(t)<0$ and $\theta'(t)>0$ : $r(t)$ is shrinking and the point spirals inward with the classical orientation (anticlockwise).
- if $r_0<1$, equations $(1)$ give $r'(t)>0$ and $\theta'(t)<0$ : there is a permanent increase for $r(t)$ while $\theta$ is decreasing ; this is an outward spiral taken in the clockwise direction.

I leave you the special case where $r_0=1$.

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation. The only part I am still trying to figure out is the last part where we are determining the behavior of the system. I was wondering why we only need to look at $r_0$ and not also $\theta_0$ because if $\theta_0$ is very large, even if $r_0$ >1, by equation (3), it would start with r<1 (again since $\theta_0$ is very large, so r(t) would be less than 1 so r'(t) would be positive in that case.  So instead, shouldn't we be looking for the initial conditions which causes r'(t) to be greater than or less than 1?

Comment: Ok so i just remembered that our domain for $\theta$ in polar coordinates is from 0 to 2pi. But 1/e^2pi is still a very small number, so shouldn't we still have to take the initial $\theta$ into account when determining the behavior of this system?

Comment: In fact, the different trajectories have a circular symmetry, i.e., the behavior of a point "launched" at $(r_0, \theta_0)$ is exactly the same as if it is launched from $(r_0,0)$, up to a rotation by $\theta_0$.

Comment: Thank you . Also as for the case where r=1, we have a stationary point right ?

Comment: That's it : all of the point of the unit circle are stationnary points.